# Have facebook scrape a different URL than what was shared

Tags: javascript, facebook, ember.js, facebook-opengraph

I have a Single Page Application built in ember.js, we have this hosted on AWS S3 and I'm trying to come up with a solution for when someone shares a URL from our site to facebook to have facebook be able to scrape the content on that page properly.

Obviously this won't work at this time because facebook does not support indexing javascript like the google search engine does. So one solution I've seen is to use apache .htaccess to redirect requests from facebook to a server file that can make a barebones html page with the necessary open graph tags like in this post

https://rck.ms/angular-handlebars-open-graph-facebook-share/

However since we're on S3 I can't do an apache .htaccess, and from what I've been able to gather from the sparse docs on how their S3 redirect rules work and what they can do I'm not sure if there is a way to do this with that method.

So my question is does facebook or open graph or even just normal meta tags have  away of allowing the user to share a url, have facebook use that but follow a link to a server generated file, and then if someone clicks that link actually have it point the user to the real single page application page instead of the server file facebook will use for the scrape data.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook supports [“pointers”](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/optimizing#optimize) to request the meta data from a different URL – but that likely won’t help you here, because the reference to the URL that serves the meta data would again have to be part of the HTML code of your original URL that you want to share.

You might do better the other way around: Let your users share the URL to your server-generated document that contains the correct meta data – and redirect human visitors that follow that link to the real target URL within your application. You can either do that via JS (`location.href='…'`), or server-side (but in that case you need to implement an exception from that redirect for the FB scraper; it can be recognized by its User Agent, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#scraperinfo)

Comment: Well the question is what about when someone copies the url from the address bar and just drops that in facebook to share (something I see even my non-tech savvy mother do on a regular basis) that's the part I'm trying to close up. I know if I have a share button I've created I can have that share whatever URL I want.

Comment: Well then make it show the “right” URL to begin with in the address bar, using HTML5 History API.